# Need to redirect a bad URL to a good URL in the same hosting which uses different domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The question is simple:

I have had a temporary domain name to put a website live before changing the current hosting of the client (for various issues with previous hosting).

So the website was live for a while using a bad URL, like:
http://www.morphartsolution.com/tau2015/

It stayed like this a few months, google put the bad URL in search results. Now that the website is live at:
http://www.marchestau.com

I would like to remove any reference to morphartsolution.com/tau2015/ . In order to do this naturally I thought to do a .htaccess redirect from morphartsolution.com/tau2015/ to marchestau.com but couldn't work it out properly.

Both morphartsolution and marchestau domains are in the same hosting (server), morphartsolution being the main domain name and marchestau an additionnal domain that works inside the tau2015/ folder.

Any clue as what would be the magic line to put in .htaccess for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Show what you have tried to do so far

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about web site management - not programming - and as such probably belongs on the [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You need a permanent redirect from

- http://olddomain.com/tau2015/

to

- http://www.marchestau.com

Add the following line to your htaccess :

```
Redirect 301 /tau2015 http://www.marchestau.com
```

If the above redirect fails, try mod-rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^tau2015/(.*)$ http://www.marchestau.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to redirect every page at http://www.morphartsolution.com/tau2015/ to  http://www.marchestau.com/ as it is , for example ,  http://www.morphartsolution.com/tau2015/example.php to http://www.marchestau.com/example.php

So put the following code inside htaccess @ tau2015 folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.marchestau.com/ [R=301]
```